# Nodejs express app with socket.io and redis store for sessions -- why more than 1 connection to Redis

Tags: node.js, express, redis, socket.io, node-redis

I have an express app (express.io specifically -- a repo that combines express and socket.io for convenience) that uses Redis for session storage.

On my development machine, when I start my app it seems to make multiple (7) connections to Redis. Why is this?

[image]

UPDATE:
This is the output I see from redis-cli MONITOR
[image]

Comment: Are the 7 connections unusual? It might just be a pool of connections so that the application can usually get an open connection immediately even when a couple of connections are in use.

Comment: No just curious, connection pooling makes sense

Comment: OK. I made a comment rather than an answer because I don't know for certain and haven't looked for documentation.